# How to mock FineUploader S3 uploads in integration tests?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Is there any way to mock FineUploaders s3 endpoint in integration tests. I'm using phantomjs for integration testing, and I'd like to test the entire upload stack, but without actually hitting S3.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to "mock" any code that sends HTTP requests, consider using [sinon](http://sinonjs.org/) to setup a "fake" server. This will allow you to handle these requests and respond appropriately.

For example:

```
// setup "fake" server
this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
// intercept all requests w/ matching method & url, 
// respond with custom status, headers, and payload
this.server.respondWith(method, url, [statusCode, headers, payload]);

// ... trigger request

// trigger custom response
this.server.respond();
```